# How can I trigger an event with a marker in leaflet.js?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an interactive time table with a map using leaflet.js. My aim is to have users click the leaflet.js marker which will reveal a side panel and show the data that is stored in an external JSON file.

I am having trouble figuring out how I can get the side panel to open when I click the marker. I’ve had a look at the leaflet.js documentation and a few other places but have had no luck. They only show how to bind a popup to a marker.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the docs here

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker

Marker has a `click` [event](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events)